# RAM UPGRADE compatibility on laptop

Tags: laptop, memory, motherboard

I have recently bought the HP Pavilion laptop 17 ab000nv (product number: E9P77EA ), i7 6700HQ, 8Gb DDR4 RAM.  specs [here](http://support.hp.com/us-en/product/HP-Pavilion-17-ab000-Notebook-PC-series/10862170/document/c05164444).  I have just purchased the RAM which seems to be incompatible:

[image: Ram Image]

The pre-installed RAM on this model is 8GB (4GB x 2). So I decided to upgrade into 32GB by purchasing a pair of HyperX Impact HX424S14IBK2/32 Notebook Memory 32 GB Kit (2 x 16 GB) 2400 MHz DDR4 CL14 SODIMM, 1.2 V, 260-Pin.

The above RAM works only when a Single Module is inserted (16GB). When both modules are inserted the laptop does not work.

How can I determine the problem and identify compatible RAM that will allow me to go to 32GB?

Comment: This question is also posted here: http://www.techsupportforum.com/forums/f108/ddr4-ram-upgrade-compatibility-dissaster-on-a-new-hp-pavilion-17-cant-find-compatib-1158113.html

Answer (score 1):

Your laptop HP Pavilion 17-ab000nv supports maximum 16 GB ( 2 x 8 GB).
DDR4-2133 and DDR4-2400 MHz. DDR4-2400 MHz will run at 2100 MHz.

Better to go with 2133 MHz.

So, if the existing single 16 GB works without issues, then you can stick with a single 16 GB or return them and replace with 2 x 8 GB modules instead.

Refer this link:
http://www.memorystock.com/memory/HewlettPackardPavilion17ab000nv.html